# Vue 3 Datepicker Typeable True Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datepicker, vuejs3

I've been using this awesome Vue Datepicker component which is this one:
https://icehaunter.github.io/vue3-datepicker/

Now, I have enabled the typeable attribute which allows the user to input date manually:

```
<template>
  <datepicker
    v-model="picked"
    :typeable="true"
    inputFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
  />
</template>
```

The problem is that it's automatically adding trailing zeros or it does autocomplete which is I don't want to trigger:

[image: Sample Demo]

How do I prevent this behavior? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add new input+mask with same v-model and get invisible default input.